# Django automatically add a foreignkey in form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the following a form and model:

```py
class Book(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    borrower = models.ForeignKey('core.User')
```

```py
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ("name", "author", "borrower")
```

```py
@login_required
def private(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            book = form.save(commit=False)
            book.save()
    else:
        form = BookForm()
    return render(request, 'borrow.html', {'form': form, })
```

In my website the user can borrow a book. Each book has its own borrower.
The problem is that the field "borrower" is translated into a html select, I would like to hide it and set it to the currently logged in user.
I would appreciate help implementing this

Comment: Where is your view?

Comment: I added the view now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove borrower from the `fields` list and set it in your view:

```
if form.is_valid():
    book = form.save(commit=False)
    book.borrower = request.user
    book.save()
```